# How do I install extra LaTeX packages in Sublime Text 3?

Tags: packages, moderncv, sublime-text

I have LaTeXTools installed and I'm trying to figure out how to install the moderncv package (or for future reference, how to install packages in general). Is this done through Sublime Text's package control?

I'm fully aware I can download it straight from [here](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/moderncv), but I don't know what to do with it after I open the file. Where is the proper place to put it? If possible, I would prefer to take a non-hands-on approach so that I don't mess things up.

Another concern is that I this is contained in MiKTeX and TeXLive, does this mean it won't work with MacTex?

Comment: Which tex distribution do you use? Texlive or miktex or mactex? You have to use their package manager. Not the package control.

Comment: @HarishKumar Just updated my question. I have MacTex

Comment: [How do I update my TeX distribution?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/55438)

Comment: Sublime Text is your editor not your TeX distribution. Since you have MacTeX installed you should have all the packages you need already, just try using them in a document.

Comment: I arrived here asking: "How can I 'Install Packages on the Fly' in Sublime Text 2/3". In case anyone else is looking for this: From reading the [LT docs](https://github.com/SublimeText/LaTeXTools) and a bit of searching there doesn't appear to be an easy method.